# Database connection VB6 to XAMPP

Tags: database, vb6

I'm totally new to vb6 and I wanna know why this code does not work. it has runtime 424 error. what do i have to do? whenever i try running it. I can't access the db it says empty. Here's the entire code.

```
    Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=db_Inventory; User=root;Password=;Option=3;"
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Add_Click()
 If Txt_Pname.Text = "" And Txt_Pprice.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter details")
 Else
    rst.Open "select * from tbl_product", db, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    rs.AddNew
    rs("Prod_Name") = Txt_Pname.Text
    rs("Prod_Price") = Txt_Pprice.Text
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    MsgBox ("Product Added!")
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Check out [MySQL Sample for Visual Basic 6.0 - read/write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024474/mysql-sample-for-visual-basic-6-0-read-write)

Comment: what is rst? You are trying to open rst. if that is a typo fine. You need to open the cn connection but you also have to set the `rs.ActiveConnection`(?) connection to cn.

Comment: On your rs.Open change the db to cn. You may have to open the connection (cn) first.